# C++ reading text from file and storing it in separate variables

Tags: c++

My .txt file is like this:

> ```
> question1 answer1  
> question2 answer2  
> question3 answer3
> ```

How can I place `question1` and `answer1` into two separate variables? I can use `getLine()`, but it will return the question and answer.

Comment: what is the separator between question and answer?

Comment: Why not use getline followed by logic needed to separate the two?

Comment: There's no such function `getLine()`, did you mean `getline()`? Also, streams have `operator>>` that parse whitespace-separated tokens. That is probably what you want to use. If you *need* to use `getline()`, then put the string inside a `std::istringstream` and use `operator>>` from that.

Comment: does question1 and answer1 have whitespace embedded??

Comment: As a workaround solution, you may want to change file format to contain question and answer on separate lines. Then you can just call `getline()` two times. If you can't or don't want, just do as answers suggest.

Comment: Sorry for being unclear, separator can be ";"
So real text can be:
this is text;answer

and i need to place "this is text" in var1 and "answer" in var2.
Also nothing is must, so getline() can be replaced.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If each question is terminated with a question mark then you can write

```
std::string line;

while ( std::getline( FileStream, line ) )
{
    std::istringstream is( line );

    std::string question;
    std::string answer;

    std::getline( is, question, '?' );
    question += '?';
    std::getline( is, answer );

    // some processing of question and answer
}
```

If there is used some other separator then you need to substitute the question mark for this separator and maybe to remove line

```
    question += '?';
```